# I want to make a form validation that will not be hindered by any other element

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

This is the reference:
[image: The form's labels have red text to the right indicating that they are required fields.]

And this is mine:
[image: The red validation text is visible for each form input except the password field.]

Mine is hindered by the input group div in the password.
Here is my code:

```js
function formvalidity1(e) {
  // console.log("yes")
  e.preventDefault();
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  console.log(inputs);
  // console.log(alert);
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (!inputs[i].value) {
      // alert.style.display = "flex";
      inputs[i].previousElementSibling.classList.remove("d-none");
      document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    } else {
      // alert.style.display = "none";
      inputs[i].previousElementSibling.classList.add("d-none");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
form {
background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form action="" onsubmit="formvalidity1(event)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fname" class="text-white">Firstname:</label>
    <span id="alert" class="d-none text-danger">Firstname is required</span>
    <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lname" class="text-white">Lastname:</label>
    <span id="alert2" class="d-none text-danger">Lastname is required</span>
    <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="uname" class="text-white">Username:</label>
    <span id="alert3" class="d-none text-danger">Username is required</span>
    <input type="text" id="uname" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phn" class="text-white">Phone:</label>
    <span id="alert4" class="d-none text-danger">Phone number is required</span>
    <input type="tel" id="phn" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="psd" class="text-white">Password:</label>
    <span id="alert5" class="d-none text-danger">Password is required</span>
    <div class="input-group input-group-md mb-2">
      <input type="password" id="psd" class="form-control">
      <div class="input-group-prepend rounded-left" onclick="passwordToggle()">
        <span id="show" class="input-group-text rounded-right">Show</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ref" class="text-white">Referral Username:</label>
    <span id="alert6" class="d-none text-danger">Referral Username is required</span>
    <input type="text" id="ref" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success w-100 font-weight-bold px-5">Register</button>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <span class="text-muted">Already a member</span>
    <span><a href="#">Sign in</a></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the error message it throws onsubmit of the form:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
    at formvalidity1 (x-investor.html:134)
    at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit(x-investor.html:61)
```

Because I used `previousElementSibling` the `previousElementSibling` of the password input is the div containing the input group instead of the alert.

Comment: You can use `inputs[i].closest('form-group').querySelector('text-danger)` to get to the <span>.

Comment: a `submit` validation handler should typically return either true or false depending upon whether or not the validation succeeds and you would call it `onsubmit='return formvalidity1(event)'`

Comment: @ChrisG i tried that but it didn't work. The console is giving me error messages like
x-investor.html:135 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')
    at formvalidity1 (x-investor.html:135)
    at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit (x-investor.html:61)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the class dots: `inputs[i].closest('.form-group').querySelector('.text-danger')`

Comment: @ChrisG what exactly do you want me to do because I already corrected this errors and added the dots that was when the console gave that error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is straight-forward: properties cannot be accessed on **null**.

*Your password input field is the first child in a div.*

according to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling), the Element.previousElementSibling returns null if the element is first child.

try selecting the `form-group`s instead of inputs and then select the alert and input using queryselector on each group.

```js
function formvalidity1(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // select all .form-group elements
  const formGroups = document.querySelectorAll(".form-group");
  
  formGroups.forEach((group) => { // loop over all the .form-groups, similar to your for loop but simpler
    
    // select the input element inside the .form-group
    const input = group.querySelector("input");

    // select the alert element inside the .form-group
    const alert = group.querySelector(".text-danger");

    // the last iteration (the '.form-group' that 
    // contains the register button) will throw an error if
    // you try to access input.value because input
    // is null, so return if input is not there

    if (!input) return; // execution stops here if input is not there

    if (!input.value) { // if input's value is empty then we remove the d-none class from the span
      alert.classList.remove("d-none");
      document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    } else { // here we add the class when there's something typed
      alert.classList.add("d-none");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work

Comment: I have updated my answer, it works now. here's a working codepen: https://codepen.io/haris_dev/pen/yLXjepj

Comment: Thanks, this worked
But I still need to understand it more.

Comment: Pls can you add more comments to it so I can understand

Comment: @SamuelEmeka added them.

Comment: Thanks i understand it now. Someone else explained it to me.